# How do I create an Akka Source[String] from a text file?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

*This seems like the simplest thing in the world, but I am just getting started and I'm stymied, so please bear with me.*

The `FileIO` object provides the `fromFile` function, which unsurprisingly returns a `Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]]`.

But I have an UTF-encoded text file and I want a `Source[String, Future[IOResult]]` -- that is, a source of a regular string, with unicode characters, not of a byte string of nonsense.

This is a Hello, World-level example, but I'm stuck.

(And what's not helping is the name collision between `scala.io.Source`, whose `fromFile` is exactly what I needed, and `akka.stream.scaladsl.Source` so if anyone could explain that to me, I'd be grateful.)

Comment: did my answer help?

Comment: @jarandaf -- sort of.  It was complicated enough I decided to use ordinary Scala I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `decodeString` function from [`ByteString`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.140568374.588201913.1464855311#akka.util.ByteString) to decode to UTF-x:

```
decodeString(charset: String): String
```

Or more commonly, for UTF-8:

```
utf8String: String
```

So, basically:

```
val path = Paths.get("/tmp/example.txt")
FileIO.fromPath(path)
  .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), maximumFrameLength=8192, allowTruncation=true))
  .map(_.utf8String)
```

Please notice `FileIO.fromFile` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

```
import akka.NotUsed

import scala.io.{Source => fileSource}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Source => strmSource}

val it = fileSource.fromFile("/home/expert/myfile.txt").getLines()
val source : strmSource[String, NotUsed] = strmSource.fromIterator(() => it)
  .map { line =>
    line.reverse
  }
```

This whole thing is lazily evaluated thus 100GB won't read at once.